# problema com window.onresize()

Tags: jquery, html, css3

Estou criando um menu responsivo dropdown utilizando a mesma estrutura html(sem criar uma estrutura maior que 1024 e outra menor que 1024), ao clicar no icone do menu dropdown as ul li aparecem, porem se eu deixar o menu aberto menor que 1024 e aumentar a tela, o menu desaparece(por causa do jquery que usa display none para esconder), fiz uma a seguinte rotina em jquery:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 1008) {
        $(".nav ul").css("display", "block");
        $(".nav").removeClass("menu_responsive");
        $(".ico_menu_dropdown").removeClass("ico_menu_aberto");
    }
    else {
        $(".nav ul").css("display", "none");
    }
}
```

porem quando eu entro no celular e dou um scrol para baixo(com o menu aberto) o menu esconde. Pelo o que eu entendi o jquery está entendendo o onresize como scroll. Alguem já teve o mesmo problema?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function verificar_tamanho(){
  var tamanho_largura = $(window).width();
    if (tamanho_largura > 1008) {
    executa o codigo;
    }else{
    executa codigo;
    }
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    verificar_tamanho();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    verificar_tamanho();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Pode usar a função acima para verificar, ele vai executar a função quando carregar o documento e quando mudar a largura da tela.
Você pode usar também media screen.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024){
  .div_display{
    display: none;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024){
  .div_display{
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Já tentei isso e não da certo, por causa do display block do .hide();

Comment: Consegue por teu código no jsfilldle? Assim posso entender melhor o problema e talvez responder por lá mesmo, obrigado!